# How to check if Qpid is installed?

Tags: bash, rpm, qpid

Trying to check if qpid is installed on RHEL6
I've done the following and nothing comes up, but it supposed to be installed

```
rpm -qa qpid
```

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to do

```
rpm -qa '*qpid*'
```

One reason is that exact package name may be something else. Don't forget the single quotes as his prevents globbing in case there are files or directories that match qpid in the current directory.

Comment: @SamGomari You know *what* is installed? You can test for what package owns a given file with `rpm -qf /path/to/file` if that helps.